# Is it ok to share official evaluation report with your mentor?

Tags: career-development

I have a mentor that does not work in the same company but is in the same industry. She has been very helpful as a sounding board, in guiding my career, etc. Is it ok to share my personal evaluation (by my boss) with her? Or would this be a burden on them and come across as me misusing our relationship?

Comment: Why can't you ask your mentor if she would be ok with that?

Answer (score 6):

Ask your manager. You may need to edit/redact it to remove details considered company confidential.

Answer (score 2):

There is no duty to your employer to keep the evaluation secret. If you would show it to your attorney, you can certainly show it to your mentor. Do be mindful of whether it contains any company secrets though, and take reasonable precaution to protect those secrets. Certainly dont publish it somewhere!

That said, your only reason for sharing a good report would be either to boast a bit, or to express your gratitude because the mentor was a key factor in your success. If that's the case, just summarize the report very briefly and emphasize the thank you.

If, however, the report is problematic, you are asking her for more help/strategy, or you're just looking for some affirmation or commiseration. If its the latter, don't burden her. If theres a concrete input that she can give, then ask her if she's willing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - you can share things that related directly to you, and that do not expose company secrets, or classified information.

What would be correct, though, is to start off by checking in on two things:

1. To your current boss - mention that you appreciate the evaluation and that you would like to get thoughts and feedback from a mentor.  Ask what an appropriate way to share this would be.  The boss may know better than you do what's considered proprietary, and since the boss may well have written some of it, you give your boss the courtesy of not sharing his/her words without checking in.
2. To your mentor - mention what your goal is, and if she'd be willing to provide input.  For example "I got commentary on my XYZ behavior, and I"m not sure what that means, would you be willing to read the evaluation and give me input?"

As a mentor - I have read emails and other feedback given to my mentees at the mentees behest.  I've always had to trust that the mentee was not giving me proprietary information and the mentee has always been able to trust that I would be discreet and not share this info.

But - trying to interpret feedback and relay it is hard work, and it's definitely nice to be asked first.

If you've started to phrase your question in step 2 and all you want is positive affirmation or commiseration, skip this process.  Paraphrase the evaluation the next time you talk to your mentor and thank her or commiserate as seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can create sample report based on your official report and then it will fair to share with your mentor. In Sample report you should include sample data and remove all official information.

I assume your mentor has interest in report formatting, layout and structure rather than your company actual data.